# How to launch windows 7 “picture import” wizard as a different user?

Tags: windows-7, picture-import-wizard

I want to run the wizard as a different login to my own.

My normal login is not an administrator on the machine (but obviously I do know the admin login/password)

**Why I want to do this?**

Both myself and my wife often want to upload pictures from our camera.
We both want to upload to a single shared location (i.e. not our individual "My pictures" folder").

It appears that the information about which pictures have already been uploaded is stored on a per user basis - which means that if I upload "all new" photos and then my wife logs on and does the same we get several duplicates uploaded.

One simple workaround would be to check the "delete picture from card after upload" but unfortunately this feature does not work with one of my cameras (a Panasonic Lumix).   So at the moment I always have to log in as my wife when I upload pictures from this camera.

Any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to or press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and run the following command:

```
runas /user:<USERNAME> "control /name Microsoft.ScannersAndCameras"
```

Replace `<USERNAME>` with the username of the account you want to run it as.  A command prompt window will appear and ask you for the password for that user account, and then a dialog box with a list of scanners and camera plugged into your computer will appear, running as that user.  From there you can start the picture import wizard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does not work: yes that command launches the "Scanners and Cameras" control panel tool but windows did not autodetect my camera and "Add device..." prompts for a driver location - I have checked the SW that comes with the camera (and online) and no such driver exists!).  I think the "Scanners and Cameras" tool is different to the "Picture import" tool that I am familiar with.